# Node Sleep Command On Password Recovery - Prevent Account Harvesting

Tags: node.js, security, password-recovery

I have pretty generic password recovery code that asks for an email, and sends a password link if email exists or prints a message if it doesn't. I want to prevent people from trying to efficiently harvest account data. My understanding that since Node is single-threaded, a sleep would block all others actions. What is a good way to prolong the action of fetching user details (to like a full second).

```
app.post('/login/recover', function(req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            // generate hash here
        },
        function(token, done) {
            var genReset = function(user) {
                if (!user) {
                    // SLEEP HERE!?!?!?
                    req.flash('failureMessage', 'No account with that email address exists.');
                    return res.redirect('/login/recover');
                }
                user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                user.resetPasswordExpires = moment().add(1, 'hours').format(); // 1 hour
                //save user here
            }
            user_manager.getUserForEmail(req.body.email, genReset);
        },
        function(token, user, done) {
            // email here
            req.flash('successMessage', 'Password link sent!');
            done(null, 'done');
        }
    ], function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/login/recover');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to keep people from accessing your endpoint too frequently.  A sleep alone wouldn't accomplish that.  An attacker could simply open up hundreds of parallel requests.

You're much better off to limit access to the endpoint via IP address.  Keep a map (js object) of IP addresses and the number of times each address has accessed the endpoint.  If an IP address has accessed the endpoint more than a handful of times, disable access for that IP address.  Reset the object and counters to 0 once every few hours.

If you still want to implement the sleep then the general pattern is with the `setTimeout` call.

```
function(done) {
  var dosomething = function() {
    //do something here
    done();
  };
  setTimeout(dosomething, 1000);
};
```

Comment: If they open hundreds of connections, they can still only get a few hundred per second. While it is probably the most effective way to do it, the cost benefit of a sleep in my specific case outweighs keeping track of IPs.